# sms uri into NFC TAG not recognised with android 4.1.1

Tags: android, sms, nfc

I encode a tag with a sms uri :
sms:067888?body=hello

This uri is correctly recognised by various applications on the store, but does not launch as default action the SMS application.

If I use a device under android 2.3.4, The sms uri open the sms application.

(I try to use various application to encode my tag with a sms uri, none permits to open the sms application with android 4.1.1)

Does any one known about or find a solution to encode sms uri correctly for android 4.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour on Android 4.1.1 is unchanged from that from 2.3.6. In both cases the "Tags" app  (or its remnant in ICS and JB) will be shown that allows you to launch the Messaging app. So in both cases, the Messaging app is not launched automatically.

The app NFC TagWriter by NXP allows you to create SMS URI messages. It also has a setting in its preferences, called "Tap to launch", that, among other things, allows you to launch the Messaging app automatically.

Comment: That's true. It was my mistake. When there is severals application that could read the tag, Android opens all, included the default application